# Windows 8: cannot set default gateway anymore (with hyper-v setup) for vEthernet

Tags: networking, windows-8, lan, hyper-v, gateway

I set up Hyper-V some time ago. Recently, on the host, the network has stopped working, even though on the guest it is still working (both using static network settings over LAN).

After checking the network settings (in control panel->network connection->network adapters) I found out that the default gateway is empty - and cannot be set/changed (I set it, windows seems to accept it, opening the ipv4 properties again, it is empty again). Also, the ipconfig /all does only return sparse, meaningless information.

(The adapter is vEthernet, the one installed by Hyper-V. I don't really know if the problem is the gateway or some other settings, since the ipconfig results are also strange, indicating the networking adapters I am seeing in control panel are not present in the system.(

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was gone after a reboot, it suddenly came back after (several) reboots. I hope it will stay like this for a while (working, i. e.).

Only additional information I found about this was here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/90cc1228-0704-4248-90a5-8f38426030d8
maybe that is helpful to someone. There are several different things mentioned to try to re-enable functionality (disabling/enabling adapter, disabling certain functionality, ...)